# Wipers stop in random position

Tags: honda

I’m failing inspection because my wipers don’t return home on my 2006 accord 4-cyl.

If I turn the wipers on for a second, they will end up straight up on my windshield. I have to hold them on for some amount of time guessing that they will end up horizontal at the bottom of my windshield.

I’ve got out of my car and pushed them back down before, which I heard was bad, but couldn’t drive with them up. The problem started when I used them with ice on my windshield.

I have the whole assembly out. Cogs look fine.

On the plug, with the engine running, white wire has 12.6v, green has 13.8 v and the yellow has continuity to the black. The yellow and black wires both have intermittent continuity to my batteries negative post. To me that seems like a problem but I can’t find a wiring diagram on it.

I saw a video where someone hammers out a tab that stops the linkage arm, but i see no such tab here. Anyone have any ideas?[image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! it could be one of two things I'm aware of: There should be some kind of sensor which reacts with the nib sticking out on the large gear. If the sensor is bad, it could cause what is happening to you. The nib should be what tells the wiper motor electronics to stop. It could also be the switch inside the car which controls the wipers (right side of your steering wheel, I believe).

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is some pin or cam that opens a set of contacts via a push rod or lever that stops the supply when the blades are in the correct position.

Used to have "fun" adjusting them - thin shimming etc to get them correct when there was no adjustment or changing the relative position of the cam with respect to the wiper arm drive gear...

Comment: Is that inside the wiper motor, and would replacing the motor solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's with the gears and connector you showed, but you missed showing the correct views.... Replacing the motor unit complete will work , as long as that is functioning correctly...